# Как осуществить самый простой рейтинг?

Tags: php, sql

Я бы сделал это с помощью отдельной таблицы **rat**, в которой хранится информация о пользователях, поставивших оценку, и сама оценка. Вывод рейтинга на страницу осуществлялся бы запросом:

```
SELECT SUM(rating) FROM rat WHERE title = "название фильма";
```

а количество проголосовавших:

```
SELECT COUNT(rating) FROM rat WHERE title = "название фильма";
```

после производились бы вычисления среднего рейтинга и пр.

Не будет ли так слишком много запросов к БД? Слышал, что `COUNT` сильно грузит процессор.

Comment: `SELECT SUM(rating) s,  COUNT(rating) c, SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) к FROM rat WHERE title = "название фильма";`

Comment: Спасибо, а как понять s, c?

Comment: alias, те то имя на которое надо ссылаться в результате запроса

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, нужно было ответить постом, я бы потавил лучший!)

Comment: еще не поздно :)

Comment: ну так чего ждете..

Comment: `WHERE title = "название фильма";` портит всю картину, даже при индексе. Лучше id фильма использовать. Как вариант - хранить дополнительно общую сумму рейтинга и количество проголосовавших, чтобы получать эти данные сразу, а не через сумму

Comment: @BOPOH тогда уж покэшировать, можно

Comment: можно по-подробнее как доп. хранить общую сумму, не до конца понимаю

Comment: @splash58, второй вариант по сути и есть кэш: есть исходные данные по каждому голосу, а есть результат подсчета. Когда надо используем первые данные, когда надо фильм - используем вторые

Comment: @ BOPOH мне бы казалось, что кэш быстрее даст ответ, чем обращение к бд, хотя понятно, что от реализации зпависит

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Получите все одним запросом

```
SELECT SUM(rating) s, 
       COUNT(rating) c, 
       SUM(rating)/COUNT(rating) r 
   FROM rat 
 WHERE title = "название фильма";
```

Answer (score 0):

Порекомендовал бы еще хранить в таблице `rat` не название фильма `title`, а его числовой идентификатор `film_id`. Если его нет, то иметь отдельную таблицу фильмов с идентификатором и названием:

```
CREATE TABLE `films` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'идентификатор',
  `name` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'название фильма',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

После чего на ID фильма в `rat` добавить индекс:

```
ALTER TABLE `rat` ADD INDEX `film_id` (`film_id`);
```

И все будет летать ;)